# OpenGL Cube is not properly texturing

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, vbo, vao

I'm attempting to texture a 3D cube made using VBO/VAOs. However I've only ever managed to properly texture 4/6 faces on the cube. I've attempted multiple solutions (ranging from defining the vertices multiple times, to attempting cubemapping - which when using a solution from a lecturer only results in the cube completely vanishing for some reason)

Initially I could properly texture the Front, Back, Top and Bottom faces. But after a few hours of messing with the coords, I have no managed to texture the Front, Back, Left and Right faces (but not top or bottom).

If anyone could help me out (and kindly explain how texture coords actually work - I get the idea on a 2D Quad, but not on a 3D VBO - or even better a good quality tutorial etc :) )

Below is the code;

***VBO Settings***

// Per-vertex position vectors

```
static float pyramidVertices[] =
{
    //Front
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //BtmLeft
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //BtmRight
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //TopRight
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //TopLeft
    //Back
    0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    //TopLeft
    1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    //TopRight
    1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,    //BottomRight
    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f //BottomLeft
};

#pragma region Pyramid Data
// Per-vertex colours (RGBA) floating point values
static float        pyramidColours[32] =
{
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

// 5 faces each with 3 vertices (each face forms a triangle)
static unsigned short       pyramidVertexIndices[] =
{
    //Front
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0,
    //Left
    0, 3, 7,
    7, 3, 4,
    //Back
    4, 5, 6,
    6, 7, 4, 
    //Top
    4, 3, 5,
    5, 3, 2,
    //Right
    2, 1, 5,
    5, 1, 6,
    //Bottom
    6, 1, 7, 
    7, 1, 0
};

#pragma endregion
static float pyramidTexCoordArray[] =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};
```

***Initialization***

```
void init(void) {

    // Request an OpenGL 4.3 context with the Compatibility profile
    glutInitContextVersion(4, 3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE);

    // Setup OpenGL Display mode - include MSAA x4
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);

    [...]
    [...]
    [...]

    texturedQuad = new CGTexturedQuad(wstring(L"Common\\Resources\\Textures\\bumblebee.png"));
    pyramidTexture = TextureLoader::fiLoadTexture(wstring(L"Common\\Resources\\Textures\\VBO\\sandstone.png"));
    exampleModel = new CGModel();
    importGSF(L"Common\\Resources\\Models\\dropship.gsf", exampleModel);

    // Setup VAO for pyramid object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &pyramidVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(pyramidVAO);

    // Setup VBO for vertex position data
    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidVertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidVertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidVertices), pyramidVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0); // attribute 0 gets data from bound VBO (so assign vertex position buffer to attribute 0)

    // Setup VBO for vertex colour data
    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidColourBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidColourBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidColours), pyramidColours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0); // attribute 1 gets colour data

    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidTexCoordBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidTexCoordBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidTexCoordArray), pyramidTexCoordArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)0);

    // Enable vertex position and colour attribute arrays
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

    // Setup VBO for face index array
    glGenBuffers(1, &pyramidIndexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyramidIndexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramidVertexIndices), pyramidVertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Unbind pyramid VAO (or bind another VAO for another object / effect)
    // If we didn't do this, we may alter the bindings created above.
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); // If we scale objects, ensure normal vectors are re-normalised to length 1.0 to keep lighting calculations correct (see lecture notes)
    //glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Best colour interpolation results


    // Setup GL_LIGHT0
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbient);     // Setup ambient light
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);     // Setup diffuse light
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, lightSpecular);   // Setup specular light

    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, ca);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, la);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, qa);

    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 15.0f);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 0.0);

    // OpenGL provides a global ambient light component - we don't want this so set to zero
    GLfloat global_ambient[] = { 0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f, 1.0f };
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);
    //
    // Load the shader we'll use for the pyramid object
    //

    err = ShaderLoader::createShaderProgram(string("Common\\Resources\\Shaders\\basic_texture.vs"), string("Common\\Resources\\Shaders\\basic_texture.fs"), &basicShader);
}
```

***Display Function***

```
void display(void) {

    // Clear the screen
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set viewport to the client area of the current window
    glViewport(0, 0, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));

    // Get view-projection transform as a GUMatrix4
    GUMatrix4 T = mainCamera->projectionTransform() * mainCamera->viewTransform();

    if (principleAxes)
        principleAxes->render(T);

    if (texturedQuad)
        texturedQuad->render(T * GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));


    // Fixed function rendering (Compatability profile only) - use this since CGImport is written against OpenGL 2.1
    glUseProgram(0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMultMatrixf((const float*)mainCamera->projectionTransform().M);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMultMatrixf((const float*)mainCamera->viewTransform().M);
    glMultMatrixf((const float*)GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(0.0f, -0.15f, 0.0f).M);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

    if (exampleModel)
        exampleModel->renderTexturedModel();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    //Define position and direction (so appear at fixed point in scene)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightDirection);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition);

    // enable texturing
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    //
    // Pyramid VBO rendering
    //

    // Use basic shader for rendering pyramid (we'll look at this in more detail next week)
    glUseProgram(basicShader);

    static GLint mvpLocationPyramid = glGetUniformLocation(basicShader, "mvpMatrix");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpLocationPyramid, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&(T.M));

    GUMatrix4 pyramidModelTransform = GUMatrix4::translationMatrix(-0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) * GUMatrix4::scaleMatrix(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
    GUMatrix4 mvpPyramid = T * pyramidModelTransform;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpLocationPyramid, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&(mvpPyramid.M));

    // Bind VAO that contains all relevant pyramid VBO buffer and attribute pointer bindings
    glBindVertexArray(pyramidVAO);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pyramidTexture);

    // Draw pyramid
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)0);

    // Unbind pyramid VAO (or bind another VAO)
    glBindVertexArray(0);


    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

***Fragment Shader***

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D texture;

in vec2 texCoord;

layout (location=0) out vec4 fragColour;

void main(void) {

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture, texCoord);
    fragColour = texColor;
}
```

***Vertex Shader***

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

layout (location=0) in vec4 vertexPos;
layout (location=3) in vec2 vertexTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

void main(void) {

    mat4 M;
    M[0] = vec4(1.0);

    ivec2 a = ivec2(1, 2);
    //vec3 b = vec3(2.0, 4.0, 1.0) + a;

    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vertexPos;
}
```

***RESULTING CUBE***
(ignore the grey bits, its just the 3D model imported "dropship.gsf")
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is expected.  The problem is that each vertex can only have one texture coordinate.  In order to solve this problem, duplicate the vertices, so you can assign a different texture coordinate to different vertices that share the same position.

Instead of using 8 vertices, I would normally use 24 vertices: 4 for each face.  By not sharing the vertices between faces, you can texture each face independently.

You could technically still share *some* of the vertices, but 24 is very small and it lets you get the normal vectors right if you want to add those later.  For smooth models with UV mapping, there is commonly a seam (or several seams) where the vertices are duplicated and this can be created in your 3D editor during the UV mapping process.

**P.S.** It is a bit confusing that the variables are named "pyramid" instead of "cube".

Comment: Thank you very much! I literally started working on this as you mentioned it! I'll let you know how it goes. And apologies for the naming, my final aim is to make a pyramid not a cube but was having trouble with the pyramid so thought cube would be simpler so I switched to making a cube temporarily (at which point when it was working I was going to convert it to a pyramid - but I'm skipping that stage now and going straight for the pyramid. Thanks again!)

Comment: Something you may also consider (later) is to put all of the attributes in an interleaved array--so you have something like `float VertexData[][8] = { ...,  { x, y, z, r, g, b, u, v }, ... };`.  This means you only need one vertex buffer instead of three, and it can make it easier to copy and paste vertex data around in your source code.  All you have to do is change the last two parameters of `glVertexAttribPointer` to get it to work.

Comment: A geometry shader would also work, this would be a good (simple) application to learn them.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: The geometry shader won't work in the general case, it's only really a quirk of geometry that would allow you to do that here, and you could equally easily use triplanar texture mapping in the fragment shader.  I wouldn't recommend this as a good case for using a geometry shader.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I took your advice on the interleaved array. And its all working now. The vast majority of my pyramids are now showing properly. However (confusingly and annoyingly enough) there is a triangle on the base of my pyramid that isn't rendering. Originally I thought I was not assigning enough memory, but I've now assigned more than enough (as well as what I thought would be exact amount) and its still not rendering the last triangle...I can't tell if its not rendering the last vertex or if its not rendering the last 3 vertices. Its not a huge issue (I can hide it) but its just annoying

Comment: I've just confirmed its not drawing the last vertex in the array for some reason? Any thoughts?

Comment: There are a lot of things that can go wrong.  Is the buffer the right size? Are you passing the right count to DrawElements? Are the vertex coordinates correct? Is the index data correct?  If culling is enabled, does the triangle have the right winding?  Any one of these could cause that problem.